# Django is always returning 404 while testing. "The requested resource was not found on this server."

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-tests

I have an Django API that I build quickly, and now I want to add some tests to ensure is stable. The problem is that Django simply refuses to let me access *any* resource on the server. It can't find any URL.

I have some models, but this test is with the `User` model.

```py
# auth/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
...
    path(
        "user/<str:email>/",
        views.UserView.as_view(),
        name="public staff user",
    ),
...
]
```

```py
# auth/views/UserView.py (Folder working as a submodule)
... # Needed imports

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

UserModel = get_user_model()

class UserView(
    generics.RetrieveAPIView,
    generics.UpdateAPIView,
    generics.DestroyAPIView,
):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = "email"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserModel.objects.all()
```

```py
# auth/tests/tests.py (Folder workign as a submodule, tests.py is a temporary name)
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APIClient, APITestCase

from authentication.models import User

import os

# Create your tests here.


class TestTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.staff_user = User.objects.create(
            email="test@account.me", is_staff=True, is_active=True
        )
        self.staff_user_password = "staff_password"
        self.staff_user.set_password(self.staff_user_password)

    def test_testing(self):
        print(User.objects.all())
        url = reverse("public staff user", kwargs={"email": self.staff_user.email})
        print(url)

        response = self.client.get(
            url,
        )
        print(response.content)
```

I have a few unused imports, but those don't matter. I create a `User` instance, and change it's password. Then, in the test, I try to retrieve it's data.

I can confirm the user exists (the shell returns `<QuerySet [<User: Employee#000>]>`) and the url works (`/api/user/test@account.me/` works with another email in the dev database).

However, `response.content` returns the following:

```
# Escaped for ease of reading
b'\n<!doctype html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n
  <title>Not Found</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n
  <h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested resource was not found on this server.</p>
\n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

I confirmed that the client can access *any* url, whether reversed or hard-coded. Can't POST or PATCH to anything either.

I've been scratching my head for a while now, but I can't find what I'm missing

---

Edit 1: I've added an edited version of the view. The logic is the same, but I'm not allowed to share the exact code.

---

Edit 2: I get the UserModel from Django's get_user_model. Added clarification

---

Edit 3: `format='json'` does not change anything

Comment: Can you show your view?

Comment: `urlpatters` is a typo - you won't get any paths matching! Change it to `urlpatterns`  :)

Comment: @michjnich typo while transcribing, but it's OK in the project

Comment: OK, going to need to see your view then :)

Comment: @GwynBleidD view added :)

Comment: @michjnich view added :)

Comment: @XceptionalBro you have used `UserModel` in the view and `User` in your test. Is this the problem or is it another transcribing error? If it is a transcribing error, please see how to write a [mre] (your given example should be able to reproduce the problem, and also no other errors should arise than the one you talk about).

Comment: The inheriting from multiple views is a little odd ... inherit from `GenericAPIView` and use mixins if you need to,

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I'm using Django's get_user_model and not importing User directly in the view. Editing now

Comment: @michjnich That view was one of the first I wrote, and I was a bit rusty. I admit it's weird, and I have to change it, but it works

Comment: @michjnich changed to mixins. Same functionality, and same error. Working just fine in the browser, "Not Found" while testing

Comment: You've clipped code here - it doesn't need a login?

Comment: @michjnich English ain't my native language, so I don't get what "clipped code" means. However, you're, this endpoint is open.

Comment: I meant "you're right"

Comment: Maybe use the DRF test classes? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/

Comment: @michjnich I'm using DRF's APITestCase, wouldn't that suffice?

Comment: Does it need `format='json'` maybe? Running out of ideas here ... what renderers do you have set in `settings.py`?

Comment: @michjnich Just tried with `format="json"`, same error. I ran out of ideas a while ago 

Comment: can you get the response.status_code?

Comment: @pleasedontbelong yeah, it's 404

Comment: The class itself is `HttpResponseNotFound`, with representation `<HttpResponseNotFound status_code=404, "text/html">`, if it helps

Comment: try adding `format="json"` to the `self.client.get(`, maybe there's a configuration problem

Comment: @pleasedontbelong done, and it's the same problem

Comment: ran out of ideas... my suggestion: add a `import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()` before the call and debug step by step

Comment: Finally got it sorted out! But I'll try that snippet next time it get stuck, seems useful, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

OMG. I didn't fix it, but I found a workaround. For everyone going through the same hell as me, here's a possible fix.

1. You're gonna want to use a Factory instead of a Client. `APIRequestFactory` works just fine
2. The `Client` couldn't find the view, but `reverse` and `resolve` are able. So you need to get the view function from those.
3. Finally, you're gonna want to generate a `request` using the `Factory`, and a `response` using the view function

Working example:

```
from django.urls import reverse, resolve
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory, APITestCase

from yourapp import models

class TestTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.staff_user = models.YourModel.objects.create(**yourdata)

    def test_testing(self):
        factory = APIRequestFactory()
        url = reverse("your reverse url name", kwargs=kwargs)
        sol = resolve(url)
        view = sol.func

        request = f.get(url) # works with every method
        response = view(request, **kwargs)
        response.render()
        print(response.content) # Finally! Response, my beloved!
```

Worst this about this workaround is that I need to pass the `kwargs` twice. I'll end up making a helper method and done

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I was looking for but your code did help me remember why I kept getting this same error ... doh!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can get this error if you are using:

```
response = client.get('my-view-name', args=[0, 1])
```

instead of ...

```
response = client.get(reverse('my-view-name', args=[0, 1]))
```

Moral: make sure you use reverse() from django.urls. Hope this might help someone frantically searching for the answer who may have come here searching the exact error but context is a little different.